# Simple Java Pipe communication does not work

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to implement really simple communication between threads using pipes.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        PipedReader reader = new PipedReader();
        PipedWriter writer = new PipedWriter(reader);
        CommitThread t1 = new CommitThread(reader);
        t1.start();

        for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++){
            System.out.println("Main - Writing to pipe " + i);
            writer.write("Number " + i);
            writer.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class CommitThread extends Thread{
    private PipedReader input;

    public CommitThread(PipedReader input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(this.input);
                while(true) {
                    String temp = buffer.readLine();
                    if(temp == null){
                        System.out.println("Commit - Empty");
                        this.input.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Commit - Input from pipe is " + temp);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged the program but it seems that the CommitThread is not getting the message from the pipe. The debugger shows the the pipe is filled but the CommitThread is not reading the data und keeps waiting.

I think it must be a really small and stupid mistake by me, but I'm not able to find it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "keeps waiting"?

Comment: The readLine() does not return, so the if-Statement is never been called.

Answer (score 0):

look here:[BufferedReader doesn't return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384186/java-bufferedreader-reading-form-socket-doesnt-return-null)

> If the server you're connecting to doesn't close the connection, BufferedReader will just hang, waiting for the next line of text.

so i think this is the Problem. simply try to read char by char

Comment: Does this makes adifference to the version in main I used?